# Nginx location rules conflict with controller

Tags: nginx, location, rules

So I have an nginx rule location set like this:

```
    location  /foo {
            proxy_pass              http://<a-service-discovery-url>/foo/;
            proxy_redirect          default;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Then I have a controller url like:

```
/foo-bar/bizz
```

The weird thing is that when I hit the controller in /foo-bar/bizz I get redirected to /foo again which is not desired.

I've tried many rule combinations all resulting in undesired behaviors:

```
location /foo/
```

or

```
location = /foo
```

or

```
location = /foo/
```

Also any regex defined with ~ won't work because the proxy_pass contains the world foo which is in the location rule.

having the trailing slash is not desired because then the user will have to explicitly write it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain, with what urls are you hitting, and what other location blocks are there, and what do you expect, and what is the bad behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dropping the trailing slash from the proxy_pass url when you add it to the location.

```
location  /foo/ {
        proxy_pass              http://<a-service-discovery-url>/foo;
        proxy_redirect          default;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: doing that results on a redirect to port 8001 (where nginx is listening) when I hit /foo (without trailing slash). :S

Comment: What directives are in your server block? The default behaviour should perform a 301 redirect from /foo to /foo/